# How do I perform automatic evaluation of my NLP model?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, metric

I have a model which converts sets of keywords to sentence, but I've to quantify it's quality. In computer vision, we would calculate the model's accuracy, I'm kind of lost and how do I go about using baselines as well, am thinking of using BLEU and ROUGE on pairs of data not used during training, is this the correct way to go? Can someone please advise?

And should I average my BLEU/ROUGE scores I got for each iteration? Is there a better metric to evaluate NLP models?

My dataset is like

```
keyword, keyword, keyword -> sentence
```

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what would be a good and bad conversion and explain why that is the case?

Comment: Do you mean an example of how the model works? It's like input is [David,eat,pizza], output = 'David ate a delicious pizza yesterday'. I guess bad conversion would be if it doesn't include those keywords or if the generated sentence is far from what is expected from the dataset?